Program hangs after executing the last command in the pipeline despite closing file descriptors and waiting for child processes to finish
Problem:
When I run a command like ./a.out "/bin/cat" test.c "|" "/bin/wc" "|" /bin/ls, the program executes /bin/cat and /bin/wc correctly, but it hangs after printing the output of /bin/ls. It seems like the last process in the pipeline isn't terminating correctly, causing the program to wait indefinitely.
What I Tried:
I’ve made sure to close file descriptors after duplicating them.
Added a loop to wait for all child processes to finish.
Question:
Why does my program hang after the last command in the pipeline, and how can I fix it so that it behaves like a normal shell pipeline?
int pip_pos(char **av)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (av[i])
    {
        if (strcmp(av[i], "|") == 0)
        {
            return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
void pipeline(char **av, char **env, int fd[2])
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
    {
        perror("");        
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        av[pip_pos(av)] = NULL;
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        execve(av[0], av, env);
        perror("");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[1]);
    }
}
void execution(char **av, int fd_input, char **env, int flag)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
        perror("");
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            dup2(fd_input, STDIN_FILENO);
            close(fd_input);
        }
        execve(av[0], av, env);
        perror("");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            dup2(STDIN_FILENO, fd_input);
            close(fd_input);
        }
    }
}
int main(int ac, char  **av, char **env)
{
    int flag = 0;
    if (ac < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <command> <args>\n", av[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    av++;
            int fd[2];
    int fd_input = 0;
    while (*av)
    {   
        if (pip_pos(av) != -1)
        {
            if (pipe(fd) == -1)
            {
                perror("");
                return 1;
            }
            flag = 1;
            pipeline(av, env, fd);
            av += pip_pos(av) + 1;
            close(fd[1]);
            fd_input = fd[0];
        }
        else
        {
            execution(av, fd_input, env, flag);
            break;
        }
    }
    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WUNTRACED) != -1)
    ;
    return 0;
}


add  a close(STDIN_FILENO) within pipeline function '    else
{
close(fd[1]);
}' block
